# Install php5.6 on 20.04 LTS

Tags: 20.04, php-fpm

I have recently installed 20.04 LTS on my Laptop. I need to install PHP 5.6. I have googled a lot regarding it, but all are suggesting to install Via Ondrej Suri PPA. I have done that but it is giving error that `unable to locate package php5.6`. I have checked their repository and found that they have support for 19.10 version but not for 20.04.

I am a noob to Linux. Please suggest an alternate way.

Comment: Off the top of my head: Perhaps try to use a Docker container with PHP 5.6? https://hub.docker.com/r/phpdockerio/php56-fpm. The docker container can share folders (Volumes) with  the host with your old stuff in there. More work than a simple upgrade but it can be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the Ondřej Surý PPA has now been updated for Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. php5.6 works fine after upgrading from 18.04 to 20.04 with `do-release-upgrade  -d`

```
$ cat /etc/lsb-release 
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=20.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=focal
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 20.04 LTS"

$ sudo apt-get install php5.6-cli 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
php5.6-cli is already the newest version (5.6.40- 
27+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.

$ /usr/bin/php5.6 -v
PHP 5.6.40-27+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.6-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2016, by Zend Technologies
```